# How do I find, sort and cat files that contain spaces?

Tags: shell, sh, freebsd, xargs

I want to cat several files that are to be found using `find`.

The file names contain spaces. This is what I have tried:

```
$  find "/tmp/database"  -name "FOO 03-11*" 
/tmp/database/01/FOO 03-11.txt
/tmp/database/03/FOO 03-11.txt
/tmp/database/02/FOO 03-11.txt
/tmp/database/05/FOO 03-11.txt
/tmp/database/04/FOO 03-11.txt

$  find "/tmp/database"  -name "FOO 03-11*" | sort
/tmp/database/01/FOO 03-11.txt
/tmp/database/02/FOO 03-11.txt
/tmp/database/03/FOO 03-11.txt
/tmp/database/04/FOO 03-11.txt
/tmp/database/05/FOO 03-11.txt

$  find "/tmp/database"  -name "FOO 03-11*" | sort | xargs
/tmp/database/01/FOO 03-11.txt /tmp/database/02/FOO 03-11.txt /tmp/database/03/FOO 03-11.txt /tmp/database/04/FOO 03-11.txt /tmp/database/05/FOO 03-11.txt

$  find "/tmp/database"  -name "FOO 03-11*" | sort | xargs cat
cat: /tmp/database/01/FOO: No such file or directory
cat: 03-11.txt: No such file or directory
cat: /tmp/database/02/FOO: No such file or directory
cat: 03-11.txt: No such file or directory
cat: /tmp/database/03/FOO: No such file or directory
cat: 03-11.txt: No such file or directory
cat: /tmp/database/04/FOO: No such file or directory
cat: 03-11.txt: No such file or directory
cat: /tmp/database/05/FOO: No such file or directory
cat: 03-11.txt: No such file or directory
```

I am using `/bin/sh` in FreeBSD 12, which is expected to be a POSIX compliant shell.

Comment: If it's a POSIX-compliant shell, `cat /tmp/database/*/FOO\ 03-11*` should work fine. POSIX mandates that words resulting from a pathname expansion be sorted lexicographically.

Comment: Thanks, that is useful information. Would that work if there is a folder under `/tmp/database/` that does not contain a file with that pattern?

Comment: Yes, it will work.